# Restoring Windows 8 client backup from WHS v1

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-home-server

I started my WHS v1 when running XP and have upgraded to W8 on 3 client machines. The connector software is installed and all backups work as they did in XP. Access to the server data is working. I tried to restore one machine and had no success. Shows quick error message and immediately reboots PC.  Researching has led to mixed opinions on whether a W8 restore can be done if created on a WHS v1 machine.

What is the truth/experience about restoring W8 from WHS v1?